# Enabling IGD multi monitor in BIOS disables external network card

Tags: drivers, display, multiple-monitors, network-adapter, chipset

I just installed a new network card in to a PC, since the internal network card had given troubles for a long time and fixing it costs more time than plugging in a new external network card. I bought the TP-Link TG-3468, and plugged it in one of the three PCIe slots, which were all empty by the way.

After a BIOS reset, the new network card worked just fine. The PC did have a dual monitor setup, where one monitor was driven by a Nvidia 745GTX, and the other was driven by the internal graphics on the i3-4150. Both are driven via VGA, as the monitors don't have any other type of input.

After rebooting, only the monitor driven by the Nvidia did work, because the BIOS reset disabled the multi monitor setup. I re-enabled that setting, and that setting only, back on. (BIOS Chipset tab> SystemAgentConf > IGD multimonitor > Enabled) After rebooting both monitors worked, but the new network card had stopped working. I reset the BIOS again, which left me again with one monitor, but a working network card. I tried it three times, with the same result.
I did update the drivers for both the video- and network card beforehand.

Does my setup make that they somehow try to diable each other? 
What could be going wrong here? 
Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What OS are you running? You should tell us. If Windows, check for resource conflicts in Device Manager; if Linux, check whether the problem exists on a Live Boot disc (indeed, it's worth checking that if you're using Windows).

Comment: Win8.1, I should've mentioned. All hardware in device manager seems to be working fine, according to their device status. No yellow triangles or anything scary. Any other methods to check for problems?

Comment: Are you saying that when the network card isn't working Device Manager shows it to be working properly?

Comment: @AFH Yes, the adapter is visible and everything, it just won't detect it if I plug in a UTP cable, while it does so perfectly when I disable multimonitor setting in BIOS.

Comment: What's at the other end of the cable? A router or switch presumably. What do the hardware connection LEDs show? Does uninstalling and reinstalling from Device Manager with the second monitor enabled make a difference? Are the monitor and network cables in close proximity? Does unplugging the second monitor cable at the computer end or turning the monitor off make a difference? I ask these questions in case the problem is cross-talk between the cables, given that your network cable is unshielded. If so, then rerouting the cables or using an STP network cable may solve it.

Comment: @AFH The length of the utp cable is ca 5m and is a CAT5e, both cables are not tightly bound together and never gave problems, so it is unlikely that they're the cause or that I need an STP cable. Plugging only a monitor in the problematic VGA output doesn't make it work. I installed the card with both monitors working, the card started working only after disabling multimonitor in BIOS. Also,i get nothing from the network card at all. 'No connections are available'. While device manager doesn't see anything wrong. I'm inclined to think it is a software bug that diables the card. Thx for helping

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Enabling IGD multi monitor in BIOS leads to a onboard realtek NIC and a pci-e connected asmedia sata controller not being found. They have disappeared from lspci.

**lspci -M** just shows:

```
00: Primary host bus
        1c.4 Bridge to 04-04
        1c.2 Bridge to 03-03
        1c.0 Bridge to 02-02
        01.0 Bridge to 01-05
01: Entered via 00:01.0
```

instead of:

```
00: Primary host bus
        1c.4 Bridge to 04-04
        1c.2 Bridge to 03-03
        1c.0 Bridge to 02-02
        01.0 Bridge to 01-01
01: Entered via 00:01.0
03: Entered via 00:1c.2
04: Entered via 00:1c.4
```

I don't know if it is a bios enumeration bug or a chipset feature (some shared resources)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for now I'm leaning towards a BIOS-Bug while enumerating devices/resources.

using:

```
sudo su
setpci -s 00:01.0 subordinate_bus=1
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

I seems to have working Ethernet card and sata controller again :) It probably wont survive a reboot, and it wont really help a 5 year old problem with windows, but perhaps someone else with the same problem.